# Non Measurable functions but sum is measurable

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I am new to Measure Theory and I am searching for the example of two non measurable functions whose sum is measurable. Can someone guide me.
Thanks

Comment: Let $f$ be a non-measurable function, then $f + (-f) =0$ is measurable.

Comment: Or take $\chi_A + \chi_{A^c}$, where $A$ is any nonmeasurable set.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is a non-measurable function, then surely $-f$ is too?

What then is $f+(-f)$?